# Makefile - Why is this sub-make not working?

Tags: makefile

I am looking for an explanation of why the sub-make doesn't work as expected. I need the sub-make because I need to run some few check before copying the files to the target directory.

The following works, but I don't have room to do my checks before the copy:

```
SRC_DIR=../src/
TRG_DIR=../../../trg/

target1.PREREQUISITES = file11.sth file12.sth file13.sth
target2.PREREQUISITES = file21.sth file22.sth file23.sth

copyToLocalTraining : $(TRG_DIR)file21.sth
        @echo $(SRC_DIR)file21.sth
        @echo $(TRG_DIR)file21.sth

$(TRG_DIR)% : $(SRC_DIR)%
        @echo cp -fp $^ $@
        @echo ls -ltr $? $@


.IGNORE:
.SUFFIXES: .sfx .sth
```

and the following does not work:

```
SRC_DIR=../src/
TRG_DIR=../../../trg/

target1.PREREQUISITES = file11.sth file12.sth file13.sth
target2.PREREQUISITES = file21.sth file22.sth file23.sth

copyToLocalTraining :
        @echo "My Checks Here"
        $(MAKE) $(TRG_DIR)file21.sth

$(TRG_DIR)% : $(SRC_DIR)%
        @echo cp -fp $^ $@
        @echo ls -ltr $? $@


.IGNORE:
.SUFFIXES: .sfx .sth
```

**No rule to make target ../../../trg/file21.sth**

I am introducing an intermediate step to see if I make it work but it doesn't:

```
SRC_DIR=../src/
TRG_DIR=../../../trg/

target1.PREREQUISITES = file11.sth file12.sth file13.sth
target2.PREREQUISITES = file21.sth file22.sth file23.sth

copyToLocalTraining :
        @echo "My Checks Here"
        $(MAKE) intermediateStep

intermediateStep : $(TRG_DIR)file21.sth

$(TRG_DIR)% : $(SRC_DIR)%
        @echo cp -fp $^ $@
        @echo ls -ltr $? $@


.IGNORE:
.SUFFIXES: .sfx .sth
```

I get: **No rule to make target intermediateStep**

Comment: I cannot reproduce your result; your second makefile seems to work. I suggest you check to make sure that `../src/file21.sth` exists, and try `make ../../../trg/file21.sth` with the various makefiles.

Comment: Same here, cannot reproduce this. Is it GNU make? Do you have only a `Makefile`? no `makefile`?

Comment: My makefile is actually called `maketest` and I call it like this `make -f maketest`. I do have another `make site` in the same directory but I am not expecting them to interfere. The source **file21.sth does exists** and a confirmation of that is that the first makefile block posted up here works. I am going to try it out in my iMac to see if it behaves the same.

Comment: I just tried the three versions in my iMac and none of them work, not even the first one. They all complaint that there is no rule to make target. The original environment, where I want them to work, is Redhat Linux.

Comment: My mistake, I was missing a file when I posted my previous comment. Correction: I just tried the three versions in my iMac and same result: only the first one works.

Comment: ¿Did you call your make files`maketest1`, `maketest2` and `maketest3` or something similar as I did, or just `makefile`?. Perhaps that explained why yours work and mine doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause. My test makefiles were named `maketest1`, `maketest2` and `maketest3`. I was wrongly assuming that $(MAKE) was doing a recursive call to itself by default, but it was actually looking for a file called `makefile`. To solve the problem I have to obtain the name of the current makefile and pass it as `-f` parameter to $(MAKE). To get the name I am now setting a new variable I am calling THISMAKEFILE at the very beginning of my test makefile before any include directive and pass it over to $(MAKE). So the final version is the following. Note that the assignment is a `:=` and not a `=`.

```
THISMAKEFILE:=$(lastword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))

SRC_DIR=../src/
TRG_DIR=../../../trg/

target1.PREREQUISITES = file11.sth file12.sth file13.sth
target2.PREREQUISITES = file21.sth file22.sth file23.sth

copyToLocalTraining :
        @echo "My Checks Here"
        $(MAKE) -f $(THISMAKEFILE) $(TRG_DIR)file21.sth

$(TRG_DIR)% : $(SRC_DIR)%
        @echo cp -fp $^ $@
        @echo ls -ltr $? $@


.IGNORE:
.SUFFIXES: .sfx .sth
```